# Using geom_rect for time series shading in R

Tags: r, date, ggplot2, time-series

I am trying to shade a certain section of a time series plot (a bit like recession shading - similarly to the graph at the bottom of [this article on recession shading in excel](https://research.stlouisfed.org/tips/200511/recession_bars.pdf)). I have put a little, possibly clumsy, sample together to illustrate. 
I first create a time series, plot it with ggplot2 and then want to use geom_rect to provide the shading. But I must get something wrong in the arguments.

```
a<-rnorm(300)
a_ts<-ts(a, start=c(1910, 1), frequency=12)
a_time<-time(a_ts)
a_series<-ts.union(big=a_ts, month=a_time)
a_series_df<-as.data.frame(a_series)
ggplot(a_series)+
  geom_line(mapping=aes_string(x="month", y="big"))+
  geom_rect(
    fill="red",alpha=0.5, 
    mapping=aes_string(x="month", y="big"), 
    xmin=as.numeric(as.Date(c("1924-01-01"))),
    xmax=as.numeric(as.Date(c("1928-12-31"))),
    ymin=0,
    ymax=2
    )
```

Note that I have also tried which also did not work.

```
geom_rect(
        fill="red",alpha=0.5, 
        mapping=aes_string(x="month", y="big"), 
        aes(
           xmin=as.numeric(as.Date(c("1924-01-01"))),
           xmax=as.numeric(as.Date(c("1928-12-31"))),
           ymin=0,
           ymax=2)
        )
```

[image]

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Code works fine, conversion to decimal date is needed for *xmin* and *xmax*, see below, requires *lubridate* package.

```
library("lubridate")
library("ggplot2")

ggplot(a_series_df)+
  geom_line(mapping = aes_string(x = "month", y = "big")) +
  geom_rect(
    fill = "red", alpha = 0.5, 
    mapping = aes_string(x = "month", y = "big"), 
    xmin = decimal_date(as.Date(c("1924-01-01"))),
    xmax = decimal_date(as.Date(c("1928-12-31"))),
    ymin = 0,
    ymax = 2
  )
```

Cleaner version, shading plotted first so the line colour doesn't change.

```
ggplot() +
  geom_rect(data = data.frame(xmin = decimal_date(as.Date(c("1924-01-01"))),
                              xmax = decimal_date(as.Date(c("1928-12-31"))),
                              ymin = -Inf,
                              ymax = Inf),
            aes(xmin = xmin, xmax = xmax, ymin = ymin, ymax = ymax),
            fill = "grey", alpha = 0.5) +
  geom_line(data = a_series_df,aes(month, big), colour = "blue") +
  theme_classic()
```

[image]

Comment: Note that this works because `aes()` was passed directly to each geom, and not to `ggplot()`.   Wierdness ensues if you supply `aes(x=Date,...)` to `ggplot()` and use `geom_rect()` with any other geom...

Comment: @Jthorpe it is about order of plotting, I could put aes inside ggplot and plot lines then rect, but then lines will be behind the rect. Of course we could use alpha. Preferences.

Comment: Ok to be specific, If you supply `aes()` to `ggplot()`, you'll need to supply all the variables in that call to `aes()`  in the data passed to `geom_rect()` and the classes of the fields will have to be consistent.  Much easier to move the call to `aes()` to the individual geoms than construct the required variables with the right formats in the data frame passed to `geom_rect()`.

Answer (score 24):

Its a bit easier using `annotate` and also note that the bounds for the rectange can be specified as shown:

```
ggplot(a_series_df, aes(month, big)) + 
    geom_line() +
    annotate("rect", fill = "red", alpha = 0.5, 
        xmin = 1924, xmax = 1928 + 11/12,
        ymin = -Inf, ymax = Inf) +
    xlab("time")
```

This would also work:

```
library(zoo)

z <- read.zoo(a_series_df, index = 2)
autoplot(z) + 
    annotate("rect", fill = "red", alpha = 0.5, 
        xmin = 1924, xmax = 1928 + 11/12,
        ymin = -Inf, ymax = Inf) + 
    xlab("time") +
    ylab("big")
```

Either one gives this:

[image]

Comment: does `annotate("rect",...)` takes in border parameter? I can not find the documentation for this. I am trying to get only a red rectangle with only the border, no fill.

Comment: @urwaCFC, Use `col=` instead of `fill=` .

Comment: I ended up using 4 `annotate("segment",...)`. Still thanks, Ill try it out for future usage.

Comment: This answer has the added benefit of working with unusual geoms that don't have an explicit x and y mapping (e.g., `geom_errorbar()`).

Comment: @Urvah, If the reason you used multiple annotates was to get multiple shaded rectangles then note that xmin and ymin can be vectors allowing a single annotate statement to be used.  e.g.  `library(ggplot2)
ggplot(a_series_df, aes(month, big)) +  geom_line() +  annotate("rect", fill = "red", alpha = 0.5, xmin = c(1915, 1924), xmax = c(1920, 1928) + 11/12, ymin = -Inf, ymax = Inf) + xlab("time")`

Answer (score 11):

To use `geom_rect` you need to define your rectangle coordinate through a `data.frame`:

```
shade = data.frame(x1=c(1918,1930), x2=c(1921,1932), y1=c(-3,-3), y2=c(4,4))

#    x1   x2 y1 y2
#1 1918 1921 -3  4
#2 1930 1932 -3  4
```

Then you give `ggplot` your data and the shade `data.frame`:

```
ggplot() + 
  geom_line(aes(x=month, y=big), color='red',data=a_series_df)+
  geom_rect(data=shade, 
            mapping=aes(xmin=x1, xmax=x2, ymin=y1, ymax=y2), color='grey', alpha=0.2)
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

```
library(xts)
library(zoo)
library(ggts)
```

### Creating an xts object

```
data<-as.xts(x=runif(228,20,40),order.by = seq(as.Date("2000/01/01"), by = "month", length.out = 228))
```

### Creating data frame of dates for which you want to crate shades

```
date<-data.frame(as.Date("2008-01-01"),as.Date("2009-01-01"))
```

### Now create plot with shaded area

```
plot_data<-ggts(data)+geom_cycle(date)
```