# What is Error: Aesthetics must be valid data columns Problematic aesthetic(s) in geom_rect and how to fix it?

Tags: r, ggplot2

I would like to make shade on certain date each year in time-series plot that is similar to this: [Using geom_rect for time series shading in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29648907/using-geom-rect-for-time-series-shading-in-r/29649406#29649406)

However, I got error:

```
Error: Aesthetics must be valid data columns. Problematic aesthetic(s): x = Date. 
Did you mistype the name of a data column or forget to add after_stat()?
```

What is the meaning of that error? I'm sure the error come from *geom_rect* function, but I don't know how to fix it.

Here is the example of my data:

```
structure(list(Date = structure(c(4018, 4019, 4020, 4021, 4022, 
4023, 4024, 4025, 4026, 4027, 4028, 4029, 4030, 4031, 4032, 4033, 
4034, 4035, 4036, 4037, 4038, 4039, 4040, 4041, 4042, 4043, 4044, 
4045, 4046, 4047, 4048, 4049, 4050, 4051, 4052, 4053, 4054, 4055, 
4056, 4057, 4058, 4059, 4060, 4061, 4062, 4063, 4064, 4065, 4066, 
4067, 4068, 4069, 4070, 4071, 4072, 4073, 4074, 4075, 4076, 4077, 
4078, 4079, 4080, 4081, 4082, 4083, 4084, 4085, 4086, 4087, 4088, 
4089, 4090, 4091, 4092, 4093, 4094, 4095, 4096, 4097, 4098, 4099, 
4100, 4101, 4102, 4103, 4104, 4105, 4106, 4107, 4108, 4109, 4110, 
4111, 4112, 4113, 4114, 4115, 4116, 4117, 4118, 4119, 4120, 4121, 
4122, 4123, 4124, 4125, 4126, 4127, 4128, 4129, 4130, 4131, 4132, 
4133, 4134, 4135, 4136, 4137, 4138, 4139, 4140, 4141, 4142, 4143, 
4144, 4145, 4146, 4147, 4148, 4149, 4150, 4151, 4152, 4153, 4154, 
4155, 4156, 4157, 4158, 4159, 4160, 4161, 4162, 4163, 4164, 4165, 
4166, 4167, 4168, 4169, 4170, 4171, 4172, 4173, 4174, 4175, 4176, 
4177, 4178, 4179, 4180, 4181, 4182, 4183, 4184, 4185, 4186, 4187, 
4188, 4189, 4190, 4191, 4192, 4193, 4194, 4195, 4196, 4197, 4198, 
4199, 4200, 4201, 4202, 4203, 4204, 4205, 4206, 4207, 4208, 4209, 
4210, 4211, 4212, 4213, 4214, 4215, 4216, 4217, 4218, 4219, 4220, 
4221, 4222, 4223, 4224, 4225, 4226, 4227, 4228, 4229, 4230, 4231, 
4232, 4233, 4234, 4235, 4236, 4237, 4238, 4239, 4240, 4241, 4242, 
4243, 4244, 4245, 4246, 4247, 4248, 4249, 4250, 4251, 4252, 4253, 
4254, 4255, 4256, 4257, 4258, 4259, 4260, 4261, 4262, 4263, 4264, 
4265, 4266, 4267, 4268, 4269, 4270, 4271, 4272, 4273, 4274, 4275, 
4276, 4277, 4278, 4279, 4280, 4281, 4282, 4283, 4284, 4285, 4286, 
4287, 4288, 4289, 4290, 4291, 4292, 4293, 4294, 4295, 4296, 4297, 
4298, 4299, 4300, 4301, 4302, 4303, 4304, 4305, 4306, 4307, 4308, 
4309, 4310, 4311, 4312, 4313, 4314, 4315, 4316, 4317, 4318, 4319, 
4320, 4321, 4322, 4323, 4324, 4325, 4326, 4327, 4328, 4329, 4330, 
4331, 4332, 4333, 4334, 4335, 4336, 4337, 4338, 4339, 4340, 4341, 
4342, 4343, 4344, 4345, 4346, 4347, 4348, 4349, 4350, 4351, 4352, 
4353, 4354, 4355, 4356, 4357, 4358, 4359, 4360, 4361, 4362, 4363, 
4364, 4365, 4366, 4367, 4368, 4369, 4370, 4371, 4372, 4373, 4374, 
4375, 4376, 4377, 4378, 4379, 4380, 4381, 4382, 4383, 4384, 4385, 
4386, 4387, 4388, 4389, 4390, 4391, 4392, 4393, 4394, 4395, 4396, 
4397, 4398, 4399, 4400, 4401, 4402, 4403, 4404, 4405, 4406, 4407, 
4408, 4409, 4410, 4411, 4412, 4413, 4414, 4415, 4416, 4417, 4418, 
4419, 4420, 4421, 4422, 4423, 4424, 4425, 4426, 4427, 4428, 4429, 
4430, 4431, 4432, 4433, 4434, 4435, 4436, 4437, 4438, 4439, 4440, 
4441, 4442, 4443, 4444, 4445, 4446, 4447, 4448, 4449, 4450, 4451, 
4452, 4453, 4454, 4455, 4456, 4457, 4458, 4459, 4460, 4461, 4462, 
4463, 4464, 4465, 4466, 4467, 4468, 4469, 4470, 4471, 4472, 4473, 
4474, 4475, 4476, 4477, 4478, 4479, 4480, 4481, 4482, 4483, 4484, 
4485, 4486, 4487, 4488, 4489, 4490, 4491, 4492, 4493, 4494, 4495, 
4496, 4497, 4498, 4499, 4500, 4501, 4502, 4503, 4504, 4505, 4506, 
4507, 4508, 4509, 4510, 4511, 4512, 4513, 4514, 4515, 4516, 4517, 
4518, 4519, 4520, 4521, 4522, 4523, 4524, 4525, 4526, 4527, 4528, 
4529, 4530, 4531, 4532, 4533, 4534, 4535, 4536, 4537, 4538, 4539, 
4540, 4541, 4542, 4543, 4544, 4545, 4546, 4547, 4548, 4549, 4550, 
4551, 4552, 4553, 4554, 4555, 4556, 4557, 4558, 4559, 4560, 4561, 
4562, 4563, 4564, 4565, 4566, 4567, 4568, 4569, 4570, 4571, 4572, 
4573, 4574, 4575, 4576, 4577, 4578, 4579, 4580, 4581, 4582, 4583, 
4584, 4585, 4586, 4587, 4588, 4589, 4590, 4591, 4592, 4593, 4594, 
4595, 4596, 4597, 4598, 4599, 4600, 4601, 4602, 4603, 4604, 4605, 
4606, 4607, 4608, 4609, 4610, 4611, 4612, 4613, 4614, 4615, 4616, 
4617, 4618, 4619, 4620, 4621, 4622, 4623, 4624, 4625, 4626, 4627, 
4628, 4629, 4630, 4631, 4632, 4633, 4634, 4635, 4636, 4637, 4638, 
4639, 4640, 4641, 4642, 4643, 4644, 4645, 4646, 4647, 4648, 4649, 
4650, 4651, 4652, 4653, 4654, 4655, 4656, 4657, 4658, 4659, 4660, 
4661, 4662, 4663, 4664, 4665, 4666, 4667, 4668, 4669, 4670, 4671, 
4672, 4673, 4674, 4675, 4676, 4677, 4678, 4679, 4680, 4681, 4682, 
4683, 4684, 4685, 4686, 4687, 4688, 4689, 4690, 4691, 4692, 4693, 
4694, 4695, 4696, 4697, 4698, 4699, 4700, 4701, 4702, 4703, 4704, 
4705, 4706, 4707, 4708, 4709, 4710, 4711, 4712, 4713, 4714, 4715, 
4716, 4717, 4718, 4719, 4720, 4721, 4722, 4723, 4724, 4725, 4726, 
4727, 4728, 4729, 4730, 4731, 4732, 4733, 4734, 4735, 4736, 4737, 
4738, 4739, 4740, 4741, 4742, 4743, 4744, 4745, 4746, 4747), class = "Date"), 
    Cu = c(1.25, 1.25, 1.25, 1.25, 1.15, 1.15, 1.15, 1.15, 1.15, 
    1.15, 1.15, 1.75, 1.75, 1.75, 1.75, 1.75, 1.75, 1.75, 1.75, 
    2.66, 2.66, 2.66, 2.66, 2.66, 2.66, 1.24, 1.24, 1.24, 1.24, 
    1.24, 1.24, 1.24, 3.71, 3.71, 3.71, 3.71, 3.71, 3.71, 3.71, 
    1.85, 1.85, 1.85, 1.85, 1.85, 1.85, 1.85, 2.13, 2.13, 2.13, 
    2.13, 2.13, 2.13, 2.13, 0.73, 0.73, 0.73, 0.73, 0.73, 0.73, 
    0.73, 0.47, 0.47, 0.47, 0.47, 0.47, 0.47, 0.47, 0.4, 0.4, 
    0.4, 0.4, 0.4, 0.4, 0.4, 0.4, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 1.12, 
    1.12, 1.12, 1.12, 1.12, 1.12, 1.12, 1.71, 1.71, 1.71, 1.71, 
    1.71, 1.71, 1.71, 1.71, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 1.28, 1.28, 
    1.28, 1.28, 1.28, 1.28, 1.28, 1.28, 0.9, 0.9, 0.9, 0.9, 0.9, 
    0.9, 1.59, 1.59, 1.59, 1.59, 1.59, 1.59, 1.59, 1.59, 1.59, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, 0.58, 0.58, 0.58, 0.58, 0.58, 0.58, 0.58, 0.58, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 0.8, 0.8, 0.8, 0.8, 0.8, 0.8, 0.8, 0.8, 
    0.8, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 0.76, 0.76, 0.76, 0.76, 0.76, 0.76, 
    0.76, 0.76, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
    NA, 0.69, 0.69, 0.69, 0.69, 0.69, 0.69, 0.69, 0.65, 0.65, 
    0.65, 0.65, 0.65, 0.65, 0.65, 0.76, 0.76, 0.76, 0.76, 0.76, 
    0.76, 0.76, 0.84, 0.84, 0.84, 0.84, 0.84, 0.84, 0.84, 0.84, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 0.68, 0.68, 0.68, 0.68, 0.68, 0.68, 
    0.68, 0.68, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 1.16, 1.16, 1.16, 1.16, 
    1.16, 1.16, 1.16, 0.67, 0.67, 0.67, 0.67, 0.67, 0.67, 0.67, 
    0.94, 0.94, 0.94, 0.94, 0.94, 0.94, 0.94, 0.6, 0.6, 0.6, 
    0.6, 0.6, 0.6, 0.6, 1.72, 1.72, 1.72, 1.72, 1.72, 1.72, 1.72, 
    1.43, 1.43, 1.43, 1.43, 1.43, 1.43, 1.43, 1.43, 1.43, NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, 1.31, 1.31, 1.31, 1.31, 1.31, 1.31, 1.31, 
    1.89, 1.89, 1.89, 1.89, 1.89, 1.89, 1.89, 0.7, 0.7, 0.7, 
    0.7, 0.7, 0.7, 0.7, 4.35, 4.35, 4.35, 4.35, 4.35, 4.35, 4.35, 
    1.48, 1.48, 1.48, 1.48, 1.48, 1.48, 1.48, 4.5, 4.5, 4.5, 
    4.5, 4.5, 4.5, 4.5, 1.95, 1.95, 1.95, 1.95, 1.95, 1.95, 1.95, 
    1.95, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 1.41, 1.41, 1.41, 1.41, 1.41, 
    1.41, 1.41, 1.01, 1.01, 1.01, 1.01, 1.01, 1.01, 1.01, 3.44, 
    3.44, 3.44, 3.44, 3.44, 3.44, 3.44, 3.01, 3.01, 3.01, 3.01, 
    3.01, 3.01, 3.01, 3.28, 3.28, 3.28, 3.28, 3.28, 3.28, 3.28, 
    0.94, 0.94, 0.94, 0.94, 0.94, 0.94, 0.94, 3.08, 3.08, 3.08, 
    3.08, 3.08, 3.08, 3.08, 3.08, 3.38, 3.38, 3.38, 3.38, 3.38, 
    3.38, 1.86, 1.86, 1.86, 1.86, 1.86, 1.86, 1.86, 1.85, 1.85, 
    1.85, 1.85, 1.85, 1.85, 1.85, 2.25, 2.25, 2.25, 2.25, 2.25, 
    2.25, 2.25, 2.25, 1.8, 1.8, 1.8, 1.8, 1.8, 1.8, 2.93, 2.93, 
    2.93, 2.93, 2.93, 2.93, 2.93, 1.09, 1.09, 1.09, 1.09, 1.09, 
    1.09, 1.09, 0.97, 0.97, 0.97, 0.97, 0.97, 0.97, 0.97, 0.57, 
    0.57, 0.57, 0.57, 0.57, 0.57, 0.57, 0.57, 0.57, NA, NA, NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 0.49, 0.49, 0.49, 0.49, 
    0.49, 0.49, 0.49, 0.49, 0.49, 0.49, NA, NA, NA, NA, 0.8, 
    0.8, 0.8, 0.8, 0.8, 0.8, 0.8, 0.51, 0.51, 0.51, 0.51, 0.51, 
    0.51, 0.51, 0.51, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 2.48, 2.48, 2.48, 2.48, 2.48, 2.48, 
    0.66, 0.66, 0.66, 0.66, 0.66, 0.66, 0.66, 0.72, 0.72, 0.72, 
    0.72, 0.72, 0.72, 0.72, 1.35, 1.35, 1.35, 1.35, 1.35, 1.35, 
    1.35, 0.65, 0.65, 0.65, 0.65, 0.65, 0.65, 0.65, 1.84, 1.84, 
    1.84, 1.84, 1.84, 1.84, 1.84, 2.56, 2.56, 2.56, 2.56, 2.56, 
    2.56, 2.56, 1.21, 1.21, 1.21, 1.21, 1.21, 1.21, 1.21, 1.73, 
    1.73, 1.73, 1.73, 1.73, 1.73, 1.73, 1.33, 1.33, 1.33, 1.33, 
    1.33, 1.33, 1.33, 1.33, 1.33, 1.33, 1.33, 1.33, 1.33, 1.33, 
    1.33, 1.33, 1.33, 1.33, 1.33, 1.33, 1.33, 1.33, 1.33, 1.33, 
    1.33, 1.33, 1.33, 1.33, 2.23, 2.23, 2.23, 2.23, 2.23, 2.23, 
    2.23, 0.89, 0.89, 0.89, 0.89, 0.89, 0.89, 0.89, 3.7, 3.7, 
    3.7, 3.7, 3.7), Pb = c(3.58, 3.58, 3.58, 3.58, 3, 3, 3, 3, 
    3, 3, 3, 3.89, 3.89, 3.89, 3.89, 3.89, 3.89, 3.89, 3.89, 
    5.4, 5.4, 5.4, 5.4, 5.4, 5.4, 4.24, 4.24, 4.24, 4.24, 4.24, 
    4.24, 4.24, 4.08, 4.08, 4.08, 4.08, 4.08, 4.08, 4.08, 3.42, 
    3.42, 3.42, 3.42, 3.42, 3.42, 3.42, 3.11, 3.11, 3.11, 3.11, 
    3.11, 3.11, 3.11, 1.68, 1.68, 1.68, 1.68, 1.68, 1.68, 1.68, 
    0.67, 0.67, 0.67, 0.67, 0.67, 0.67, 0.67, 1.19, 1.19, 1.19, 
    1.19, 1.19, 1.19, 1.19, 1.63, 1.63, 1.63, 1.63, 1.63, 1.63, 
    1.63, 2.22, 2.22, 2.22, 2.22, 2.22, 2.22, 2.22, 2.25, 2.25, 
    2.25, 2.25, 2.25, 2.25, 2.25, 1.93, 1.93, 1.93, 1.93, 1.93, 
    1.93, 1.93, 1.98, 1.98, 1.98, 1.98, 1.98, 1.98, 1.98, 1.98, 
    1.3, 1.3, 1.3, 1.3, 1.3, 1.3, 1.44, 1.44, 1.44, 1.44, 1.44, 
    1.44, 1.44, 1.44, 0.75, 0.75, 0.75, 0.75, 0.75, 0.75, 1.02, 
    1.02, 1.02, 1.02, 1.02, 1.02, 1.02, 1.02, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 0.31, 0.31, 0.31, 0.31, 
    0.31, 0.31, 0.31, 0.31, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
    NA, NA, 0.34, 0.34, 0.34, 0.34, 0.34, 0.34, 0.34, 0.34, 0.3, 
    0.3, 0.3, 0.3, 0.3, 0.3, 0.3, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 0.76, 0.76, 0.76, 0.76, 0.76, 0.76, 0.76, 
    1.88, 1.88, 1.88, 1.88, 1.88, 1.88, 1.88, 1.88, NA, NA, NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, 0.49, 0.49, 0.49, 0.49, 0.49, 0.49, 0.49, 4.57, 
    4.57, 4.57, 4.57, 4.57, 4.57, 4.57, 3.93, 3.93, 3.93, 3.93, 
    3.93, 3.93, 3.93, 7.19, 7.19, 7.19, 7.19, 7.19, 7.19, 7.19, 
    7.55, 7.55, 7.55, 7.55, 7.55, 7.55, 7.55, 5.37, 5.37, 5.37, 
    5.37, 5.37, 5.37, 5.37, 4.64, 4.64, 4.64, 4.64, 4.64, 4.64, 
    4.64, 9.34, 9.34, 9.34, 9.34, 9.34, 9.34, 9.34, 9.34, 4.98, 
    4.98, 4.98, 4.98, 4.98, 4.98, 4.11, 4.11, 4.11, 4.11, 4.11, 
    4.11, 4.11, 5.7, 5.7, 5.7, 5.7, 5.7, 5.7, 5.7, 2.1, 2.1, 
    2.1, 2.1, 2.1, 2.1, 2.1, 2.1, 3.31, 3.31, 3.31, 3.31, 3.31, 
    3.31, 3.11, 3.11, 3.11, 3.11, 3.11, 3.11, 3.11, 3.05, 3.05, 
    3.05, 3.05, 3.05, 3.05, 3.05, 2.24, 2.24, 2.24, 2.24, 2.24, 
    2.24, 2.24, 2.24, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
    2.47, 2.47, 2.47, 2.47, 2.47, 2.47, 2.47, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 1.27, 
    1.27, 1.27, 1.27, 1.27, 1.27, 1.27, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 2.72, 2.72, 2.72, 2.72, 2.72, 
    2.72, 2.72, 2.72, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, 0.61, 0.61, 0.61, 0.61, 0.61, 0.61, 0.61, 0.61, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 2.26, 2.26, 2.26, 2.26, 2.26, 2.26, 
    2.26, 1.11, 1.11, 1.11, 1.11, 1.11, 1.11, 1.11, 1.11, 1.11, 
    1.11, 1.11, 1.11, 1.11, 1.11, 1.11, 1.11, 1.11, 1.11, 1.11, 
    1.11, 1.11, 1.11, 1.11, 1.11, 1.11, 1.11, 1.11, 1.11, 1.63, 
    1.63, 1.63, 1.63, 1.63, 1.63, 1.63, 1.27, 1.27, 1.27, 1.27, 
    1.27, 1.27, 1.27, 1.48, 1.48, 1.48, 1.48, 1.48), V = c(0.847, 
    0.847, 0.847, 0.847, 0.83, 0.83, 0.83, 0.83, 0.83, 0.83, 
    0.83, 1.178, 1.178, 1.178, 1.178, 1.178, 1.178, 1.178, 1.178, 
    1.6, 1.6, 1.6, 1.6, 1.6, 1.6, 1.351, 1.351, 1.351, 1.351, 
    1.351, 1.351, 1.351, 0.92, 0.92, 0.92, 0.92, 0.92, 0.92, 
    0.92, 0.633, 0.633, 0.633, 0.633, 0.633, 0.633, 0.633, 0.755, 
    0.755, 0.755, 0.755, 0.755, 0.755, 0.755, 0.268, 0.268, 0.268, 
    0.268, 0.268, 0.268, 0.268, 0.116, 0.116, 0.116, 0.116, 0.116, 
    0.116, 0.116, 0.145, 0.145, 0.145, 0.145, 0.145, 0.145, 0.145, 
    0.138, 0.138, 0.138, 0.138, 0.138, 0.138, 0.138, 0.392, 0.392, 
    0.392, 0.392, 0.392, 0.392, 0.392, 0.438, 0.438, 0.438, 0.438, 
    0.438, 0.438, 0.438, 0.34, 0.34, 0.34, 0.34, 0.34, 0.34, 
    0.34, 0.517, 0.517, 0.517, 0.517, 0.517, 0.517, 0.517, 0.517, 
    0.269, 0.269, 0.269, 0.269, 0.269, 0.269, 0.673, 0.673, 0.673, 
    0.673, 0.673, 0.673, 0.673, 0.673, 0.161, 0.161, 0.161, 0.161, 
    0.161, 0.161, 0.535, 0.535, 0.535, 0.535, 0.535, 0.535, 0.535, 
    0.448, 0.448, 0.448, 0.448, 0.448, 0.448, 0.448, 0.091, 0.091, 
    0.091, 0.091, 0.091, 0.091, 0.091, 0.091, 0.121, 0.121, 0.121, 
    0.121, 0.121, 0.121, 0.035, 0.035, 0.035, 0.035, 0.035, 0.035, 
    0.035, 0.045, 0.045, 0.045, 0.045, 0.045, 0.045, 0.045, 0.108, 
    0.108, 0.108, 0.108, 0.108, 0.108, 0.108, 0.278, 0.278, 0.278, 
    0.278, 0.278, 0.278, 0.278, 0.162, 0.162, 0.162, 0.162, 0.162, 
    0.162, 0.162, 0.162, 0.162, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 0.064, 0.064, 
    0.064, 0.064, 0.064, 0.064, 0.064, 0.064, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
    NA, NA, 0.062, 0.062, 0.062, 0.062, 0.062, 0.062, 0.062, 
    0.095, 0.095, 0.095, 0.095, 0.095, 0.095, 0.095, 0.031, 0.031, 
    0.031, 0.031, 0.031, 0.031, 0.031, 0.343, 0.343, 0.343, 0.343, 
    0.343, 0.343, 0.343, 0.767, 0.767, 0.767, 0.767, 0.767, 0.767, 
    0.767, 0.442, 0.442, 0.442, 0.442, 0.442, 0.442, 0.442, 1.085, 
    1.085, 1.085, 1.085, 1.085, 1.085, 1.085, 0.711, 0.711, 0.711, 
    0.711, 0.711, 0.711, 0.711, 1.036, 1.036, 1.036, 1.036, 1.036, 
    1.036, 1.036, 0.624, 0.624, 0.624, 0.624, 0.624, 0.624, 0.624, 
    0.624, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
    0.132, 0.132, 0.132, 0.132, 0.132, 0.132, 0.132, 0.032, 0.032, 
    0.032, 0.032, 0.032, 0.032, 0.032, 0.032, 0.134, 0.134, 0.134, 
    0.134, 0.134, 0.134, 0.065, 0.065, 0.065, 0.065, 0.065, 0.065, 
    0.065, 0.201, 0.201, 0.201, 0.201, 0.201, 0.201, 0.201, 0.109, 
    0.109, 0.109, 0.109, 0.109, 0.109, 0.109, 1.189, 1.189, 1.189, 
    1.189, 1.189, 1.189, 1.189, 0.479, 0.479, 0.479, 0.479, 0.479, 
    0.479, 0.479, 0.565, 0.565, 0.565, 0.565, 0.565, 0.565, 0.565, 
    0.243, 0.243, 0.243, 0.243, 0.243, 0.243, 0.243, 0.142, 0.142, 
    0.142, 0.142, 0.142, 0.142, 0.142, 2.73, 2.73, 2.73, 2.73, 
    2.73, 2.73, 2.73, 1.848, 1.848, 1.848, 1.848, 1.848, 1.848, 
    1.848, 2.126, 2.126, 2.126, 2.126, 2.126, 2.126, 2.126, 2.59, 
    2.59, 2.59, 2.59, 2.59, 2.59, 2.59, 2.077, 2.077, 2.077, 
    2.077, 2.077, 2.077, 2.077, 0.912, 0.912, 0.912, 0.912, 0.912, 
    0.912, 0.912, 1.944, 1.944, 1.944, 1.944, 1.944, 1.944, 1.944, 
    1.944, 1.38, 1.38, 1.38, 1.38, 1.38, 1.38, 1.384, 1.384, 
    1.384, 1.384, 1.384, 1.384, 1.384, 0.807, 0.807, 0.807, 0.807, 
    0.807, 0.807, 0.807, 0.573, 0.573, 0.573, 0.573, 0.573, 0.573, 
    0.573, 0.573, 0.81, 0.81, 0.81, 0.81, 0.81, 0.81, 0.598, 
    0.598, 0.598, 0.598, 0.598, 0.598, 0.598, 0.535, 0.535, 0.535, 
    0.535, 0.535, 0.535, 0.535, 0.4, 0.4, 0.4, 0.4, 0.4, 0.4, 
    0.4, 0.063, 0.063, 0.063, 0.063, 0.063, 0.063, 0.063, 0.063, 
    0.063, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 0.139, 0.139, 0.139, 0.139, 
    0.139, 0.139, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
    NA, NA, 0.015, 0.015, 0.015, 0.015, 0.015, 0.015, 0.015, 
    0.024, 0.024, 0.024, 0.024, 0.024, 0.024, 0.024, 0.081, 0.081, 
    0.081, 0.081, 0.081, 0.081, 0.081, 0.08, 0.08, 0.08, 0.08, 
    0.08, 0.08, 0.08, 0.051, 0.051, 0.051, 0.051, 0.051, 0.051, 
    0.051, 0.051, 0.428, 0.428, 0.428, 0.428, 0.428, 0.428, 0.125, 
    0.125, 0.125, 0.125, 0.125, 0.125, 0.125, 0.044, 0.044, 0.044, 
    0.044, 0.044, 0.044, 0.044, 0.057, 0.057, 0.057, 0.057, 0.057, 
    0.057, 0.057, 0.057, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, 0.548, 0.548, 0.548, 0.548, 0.548, 0.548, 0.048, 
    0.048, 0.048, 0.048, 0.048, 0.048, 0.048, 0.019, 0.019, 0.019, 
    0.019, 0.019, 0.019, 0.019, 0.04, 0.04, 0.04, 0.04, 0.04, 
    0.04, 0.04, 0.06, 0.06, 0.06, 0.06, 0.06, 0.06, 0.06, 0.051, 
    0.051, 0.051, 0.051, 0.051, 0.051, 0.051, 0.105, 0.105, 0.105, 
    0.105, 0.105, 0.105, 0.105, 0.105, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
    0.261, 0.261, 0.261, 0.261, 0.261, 0.261, 0.261, 0.176, 0.176, 
    0.176, 0.176, 0.176, 0.176, 0.176, 0.176, 0.176, 0.176, 0.176, 
    0.176, 0.176, 0.176, 0.176, 0.176, 0.176, 0.176, 0.176, 0.176, 
    0.176, 0.176, 0.176, 0.176, 0.176, 0.176, 0.176, 0.176, 0.327, 
    0.327, 0.327, 0.327, 0.327, 0.327, 0.327, 0.254, 0.254, 0.254, 
    0.254, 0.254, 0.254, 0.254, 0.258, 0.258, 0.258, 0.258, 0.258
    ), Zn = c(6.19, 6.19, 6.19, 6.19, 8.7, 8.7, 8.7, 8.7, 8.7, 
    8.7, 8.7, 8.9, 8.9, 8.9, 8.9, 8.9, 8.9, 8.9, 8.9, 9.91, 9.91, 
    9.91, 9.91, 9.91, 9.91, 7.8, 7.8, 7.8, 7.8, 7.8, 7.8, 7.8, 
    11.89, 11.89, 11.89, 11.89, 11.89, 11.89, 11.89, 6.86, 6.86, 
    6.86, 6.86, 6.86, 6.86, 6.86, 7.6, 7.6, 7.6, 7.6, 7.6, 7.6, 
    7.6, 2.5, 2.5, 2.5, 2.5, 2.5, 2.5, 2.5, 2.18, 2.18, 2.18, 
    2.18, 2.18, 2.18, 2.18, 2.18, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 3.09, 3.09, 3.09, 3.09, 3.09, 3.09, 
    3.09, 4.43, 4.43, 4.43, 4.43, 4.43, 4.43, 4.43, 2.28, 2.28, 
    2.28, 2.28, 2.28, 2.28, 2.28, 3.25, 3.25, 3.25, 3.25, 3.25, 
    3.25, 3.25, 3.25, 3.25, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 3.71, 3.71, 3.71, 
    3.71, 3.71, 3.71, 3.71, 3.71, 0.89, 0.89, 0.89, 0.89, 0.89, 
    0.89, 1.49, 1.49, 1.49, 1.49, 1.49, 1.49, 1.49, 1.11, 1.11, 
    1.11, 1.11, 1.11, 1.11, 1.11, 1.11, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 0.87, 0.87, 0.87, 0.87, 0.87, 
    0.87, 0.87, 0.79, 0.79, 0.79, 0.79, 0.79, 0.79, 0.79, 0.79, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 1.53, 
    1.53, 1.53, 1.53, 1.53, 1.53, 1.53, 1.53, 0.8, 0.8, 0.8, 
    0.8, 0.8, 0.8, 1.65, 1.65, 1.65, 1.65, 1.65, 1.65, 1.65, 
    1.65, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 0.88, 0.88, 0.88, 0.88, 0.88, 
    0.88, 0.88, 1.33, 1.33, 1.33, 1.33, 1.33, 1.33, 1.33, 1.49, 
    1.49, 1.49, 1.49, 1.49, 1.49, 1.49, 1.8, 1.8, 1.8, 1.8, 1.8, 
    1.8, 1.8, 2.86, 2.86, 2.86, 2.86, 2.86, 2.86, 2.86, 0.97, 
    0.97, 0.97, 0.97, 0.97, 0.97, 0.97, 2.2, 2.2, 2.2, 2.2, 2.2, 
    2.2, 2.2, 1.09, 1.09, 1.09, 1.09, 1.09, 1.09, 1.09, 3.06, 
    3.06, 3.06, 3.06, 3.06, 3.06, 3.06, 1.86, 1.86, 1.86, 1.86, 
    1.86, 1.86, 1.86, 2.41, 2.41, 2.41, 2.41, 2.41, 2.41, 2.41, 
    1.47, 1.47, 1.47, 1.47, 1.47, 1.47, 1.47, 2.88, 2.88, 2.88, 
    2.88, 2.88, 2.88, 2.88, 2.35, 2.35, 2.35, 2.35, 2.35, 2.35, 
    2.35, 2.35, 1.41, 1.41, 1.41, 1.41, 1.41, 1.41, 2.02, 2.02, 
    2.02, 2.02, 2.02, 2.02, 2.02, 3.31, 3.31, 3.31, 3.31, 3.31, 
    3.31, 3.31, 1.3, 1.3, 1.3, 1.3, 1.3, 1.3, 1.3, 7, 7, 7, 7, 
    7, 7, 7, 3.6, 3.6, 3.6, 3.6, 3.6, 3.6, 3.6, 9.07, 9.07, 9.07, 
    9.07, 9.07, 9.07, 9.07, 3.28, 3.28, 3.28, 3.28, 3.28, 3.28, 
    3.28, 1.55, 1.55, 1.55, 1.55, 1.55, 1.55, 1.55, 9.58, 9.58, 
    9.58, 9.58, 9.58, 9.58, 9.58, 7.54, 7.54, 7.54, 7.54, 7.54, 
    7.54, 7.54, 13.86, 13.86, 13.86, 13.86, 13.86, 13.86, 13.86, 
    14.27, 14.27, 14.27, 14.27, 14.27, 14.27, 14.27, 9.59, 9.59, 
    9.59, 9.59, 9.59, 9.59, 9.59, 7.08, 7.08, 7.08, 7.08, 7.08, 
    7.08, 7.08, 18.08, 18.08, 18.08, 18.08, 18.08, 18.08, 18.08, 
    18.08, 10.95, 10.95, 10.95, 10.95, 10.95, 10.95, 7.36, 7.36, 
    7.36, 7.36, 7.36, 7.36, 7.36, 6.18, 6.18, 6.18, 6.18, 6.18, 
    6.18, 6.18, 5.25, 5.25, 5.25, 5.25, 5.25, 5.25, 5.25, 5.25, 
    5.4, 5.4, 5.4, 5.4, 5.4, 5.4, 6.39, 6.39, 6.39, 6.39, 6.39, 
    6.39, 6.39, 4.33, 4.33, 4.33, 4.33, 4.33, 4.33, 4.33, 2.92, 
    2.92, 2.92, 2.92, 2.92, 2.92, 2.92, 0.89, 0.89, 0.89, 0.89, 
    0.89, 0.89, 0.89, 0.89, 0.89, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
    1.06, 1.06, 1.06, 1.06, 1.06, 1.06, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 5.21, 5.21, 5.21, 5.21, 5.21, 
    5.21, 5.21, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 2.09, 2.09, 2.09, 2.09, 
    2.09, 2.09, 2.09, 2.03, 2.03, 2.03, 2.03, 2.03, 2.03, 2.03, 
    2.03, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 2.63, 2.63, 2.63, 2.63, 2.63, 
    2.63, 2.63, 4.31, 4.31, 4.31, 4.31, 4.31, 4.31, 4.31, 1.77, 
    1.77, 1.77, 1.77, 1.77, 1.77, 1.77, 4.15, 4.15, 4.15, 4.15, 
    4.15, 4.15, 4.15, 2.22, 2.22, 2.22, 2.22, 2.22, 2.22, 2.22, 
    2.22, 2.22, 2.22, 2.22, 2.22, 2.22, 2.22, 2.22, 2.22, 2.22, 
    2.22, 2.22, 2.22, 2.22, 2.22, 2.22, 2.22, 2.22, 2.22, 2.22, 
    2.22, 5.24, 5.24, 5.24, 5.24, 5.24, 5.24, 5.24, 2.7, 2.7, 
    2.7, 2.7, 2.7, 2.7, 2.7, 7.47, 7.47, 7.47, 7.47, 7.47)), row.names = 167:896, class = "data.frame")
```

Here is my code:

```
library (ggplot2)
library (dplyr)
library (tidyr)

shade <-
df1 %>%
transmute(year = year(Date)) %>%
unique() %>%
mutate(
from = as.Date(paste0(year, "-02-21")),
to   = as.Date(paste0(year, "-04-30"))
)

ggplot(df1, aes(x=Date)) + 
geom_rect(data = shade, aes(xmin = from, xmax = to, ymin = -Inf, ymax = Inf), color='grey', alpha=0.2) +
geom_line( aes(y=V, color='V'))  +  geom_line( aes(y= Cu / coeff, color = 'Cu')) +
geom_line( aes(y= Pb / coeff, color = 'Pb')) +  geom_line( aes(y=  / coeff, color = 'Zn')) +
scale_y_continuous(name = "V", sec.axis = sec_axis(~.*coeff, name = "Cu, Pb, Zn"))+
theme_bw()+ theme(legend.position = c(0.2, 0.9),legend.direction="horizontal")+labs(color = NULL, fill = NULL)
```

If you have any idea what happened and how to fix it, please let me know. Thank you.

Best regards.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to use only `ggplot(df1)` and not putting `aes()` inside `ggplot()`, each `geom_line` read `df1` and `geom_rect` read `shade`.

```
ggplot(df1) + 
  geom_line( aes(x=Date, y=V, color='V'))  +  
  geom_line( aes(x=Date, y= Cu, color = 'Cu')) +
  geom_line( aes(x=Date, y= Pb, color = 'Pb')) +  
  geom_line( aes(x=Date, y= Zn, color = 'Zn')) +
  geom_rect(data = shade, aes(xmin = from, xmax = to, ymin = -Inf, ymax = Inf), color='grey', alpha=0.2) +
  scale_y_continuous(name = "V", sec.axis = sec_axis(~., name = "Cu, Pb, Zn"))+
  theme_bw()+ theme(legend.position = c(0.2, 0.9),legend.direction="horizontal")+labs(color = NULL, fill = NULL)


# or u can use

ggplot() + 
  geom_line(data = df1, aes(x=Date, y=V, color='V'))  +  
  geom_line(data = df1, aes(x=Date, y= Cu, color = 'Cu')) +
  geom_line(data = df1, aes(x=Date, y= Pb, color = 'Pb')) +  
  geom_line(data = df1, aes(x=Date, y= Zn, color = 'Zn')) +
  geom_rect(data = shade, aes(xmin = from, xmax = to, ymin = -Inf, ymax = Inf), color='grey', alpha=0.2) +
  scale_y_continuous(name = "V", sec.axis = sec_axis(~., name = "Cu, Pb, Zn"))+
  theme_bw()+ theme(legend.position = c(0.2, 0.9),legend.direction="horizontal")+labs(color = NULL, fill = NULL)
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion the error you are getting is beacuse `geom_rect()` is trying to find columns (`Date` in this case) in previously declared `aes()`.

I couldn't test my theory since there are some problems with your code (e.g. no `coeff` in `df1` object).

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to put in coeff variable. It should: coeff <- 30